# Searching for a number within an xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version= "1.0"?>
<r>
    <floor _number='1'>
    <shop>
        <name>undefined</name>
        <number>101</number>
    </shop>
</floor>
<floor _number='2'>
    <shop>
        <name>undefined</name>
        <number>201</number>
    </shop>
</floor>
</r>
```

What if I wanted to search if there´s a store on floor '1' with a number of 301?

How could I do that?
Through actionscript3?

I thought something like this, but it always returns true.
Where 'xml' is the xml instance.

```
var found:Boolean = Boolean(xml.r.floor.(@_number=='1').shop.(number==301))
```

It always returns me true, why?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if there´s no 301 number

Comment: try `trace(xml.floor.(@_number == '1').shop.number == '301');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. xml.r.floor.(@_number=='1').shop.(number==301) is an XMLList which may be empty if you have no such store. Doing a Boolean(some_xmlList) will alwais be true.
2. to fix it use

   result:Boolean = (xml.r.floor.(@_number=='1').shop.(number==301) as XMLList).length() > 0;